# Profile of users without QAs and with at least one rarest badge

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page, mobile-web

I've noticed a bug using Google Chrome on an Android 7.0. The normal user profile Rarest badge section should look like this

[image: Normal rarest badge section]

When going to the profile of a new user that has no QAs and at least one rarest badge, then the rarest badge section has wrong format (more to the right side of the page) as you can see in the following image

[image: Rarest badges from user with few badges]

This happens across networks, that's why I'm sharing it here.

A way to reproduce using SO in the Android's browser: Click in Users > New Users > Creation Date. Then there you can see which users have at least one badge and click there. It can happen the badge isn't rare, so then nothing shows up. But if the badge is rare, you'll see that behavior.

Some of the users (to note the bahavior might change from the moment the users add one question or answer)

. https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/38908/user1898829

. https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/38901/marcus-edwards

. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/716568/sree-vishnu

. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/716536/faakhir

Comment: You are most likely searching using Desktop version. Like that I also had troubles finding it. Just shared now some profiles, had to go back to the phone again and that took some time.